# Como puedo darle mantenimiento a una app hecha en Laravel que ha sido subida al Cpanel?

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

Me surge esta duda al subir mi primera app Laravel al Cpanel. Me  gustaría saber de que forma mas fácil poder subir actualizaciones posteriores, si pudiera enlazar git o alguna otra herramienta para poder dar un mejor mantenimiento.

Los leo.

Comment: Opciones varias, pero depende que tanto te permita hacer tu servidor, siendo lo más básico y elemental el ftp

Comment: Estoy utilizando Bluehosting. Lo has probado?

Comment: Deberías tener un sistema de prueba o desarrollo, de preferencia en tu computadora, donde hagas todas las modificaciones, realices las pruebas necesarias y, cuando todo esté listo, subirlo al servidor por FTP, como bien te sugirió @BetaM. Hay paquetes que te permiten [actualizar el Framework](https://github.com/codedge/laravel-selfupdater), pero desconozco que tan fiable es o si los hay también para códigos propios y de terceros.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios. Los tomare en cuenta.